# APPCRASH error C# on Application Exit/Close after Deployment

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment, crash

I get this error every time I exit from the software installed on a Windows 7 machine. 
This only happened on another computer after I deployed and installed the program there. But on the computer where I developed this, this didnt happen. What is the problem for this?

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   Dumisoft.exe
Application Version:    1.0.0.0
Application Timestamp:  51cc3663
Fault Module Name:  IMM32.DLL
Fault Module Version:   6.1.7601.17514
Fault Module Timestamp: 4ce7b845
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   000030c4
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Anyway Im using MS Access here as a Database. My application has flash and htm file.

Comment: What version of Windows is the machine running? Did you install as an Administrator (Windows 7 etc ensure you **"Run as Administrator"**).

Comment: O yah. Windows 7. Wait ill try..

Comment: You get blue screen i suppose. Are you installing hardware drivers or something like this? Or your app interacting with hardware device?

Comment: @Belogix: I still got the same error.

Comment: @kostasch: Theres no blue screen. No im not installing hardware drivers and not interacting with it.

Comment: You can try doing a mini-dump as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528776/windows-c-is-it-possible-to-find-the-line-of-code-where-exception-was-thrown and expanded on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964478/displaying-exception-debug-information-to-users (not accepted answer but second one by Hans Passant).

Comment: Wait im having a hard time here. This is the first time that it happens. -.-

Comment: This mini-dump will know where the error is?

Comment: You will need a full memory mini dump so as to locate the memory culprit (c0000005 means access violation). If you are not capable of analyzing such dumps, you will have to open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and see if Microsoft can help you out. It is very likely that you forgot to free native resources, but you won't get any clue easily.

Answer (score 1):

This could have happened to me
To fix this error, it is best to make sure that you reference in the copy destination
**For example: YourComponent copy local = True**

good luck. :)